# Express Sub-domain Routing

Tags: javascript, express

I am having a big issue in setting up sub-domain and it routing in Express Node.
I have multiple sub-domain (web, mobile, lite). I am looking for a way to route the user according to their device and their browser.
if user is on desktop it should be route to *web.*.
if user is on mobile it should be route to *mobile.*.
if user is on mobile chrome(browser) or java script enable it should be route to *lite.*.

Comment: I would assume some piece of middle wear that checks the incoming user-agent and redirects the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install and use the useragent module, then put a bit of custom middleware before all you routes.

```
useragent = require('useragent');

//...

app.use((req,res,next) => {
  let ua = useragent.is(req.headers['user-agent']);
  if(ua.android || ua.mobile_safari){
    res.redirect('http://mobile.mysite.com');
  }
  else next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, the user agent does serve another purpose.

Comment: @BadmusKaybee  If this answers the question it is good to mark as the answer to the problem.  If not, what is missing?

Comment: Thanks @Christ. But i wonder how facebook mobile(m.facebook.com) authomatically change their design base on device.

Comment: @BadmusKaybee This is responsive design, that most websites support without having a dedicated mobile only site.  Google responsive design to learn how to do it, the best way is usually to start with a framework like Bootstrap